# How are list comprehensions implemented in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, monads, ghc

- Are list comprehensions simply a language feature?
- What's the easiest way to fake a list comprehension using pure Haskell?
- Do you have to use a do block/`>>=` to do this or could you use some other
  method for hacking a list comprehension together?

Clarification: By "fake" a list comprehension I mean create a function that takes the same input and produces the same input, i.e. a form for the return values, lists to crunch together, and a predicate or multiple predicates.

Comment: [This](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/List_comprehension) may answer some of your questions.  It explains how comprehensions are syntactic sugar for do notation, which themselves are just syntactic sugar for `>>=`, but I really don't know what you mean by "fake a list comprehension using pure Haskell".  It _is_ pure Haskell, according to the Haskell specification.

Comment: I added a clarification, but I really don't understand why this is getting so many down votes, I'm just asking how a list comprehension could be written without using a list comprehension to better understand them.

Comment: I think it's a legitimate question.  And I upvoted it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[Section 3.11](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/exps.html#list-comprehensions) in the Haskell report describes exactly what list comprehensions mean, and how to translate them away.

If you want monad comprehensions you basically need to replace `[e]` by `return e`, `[]` by `mzero`, and `concatMap` by `(>>=)` in the translation.

Answer (score 13):

To augment `augustss`'s answer, if you have something like:

```
[(x, y) | x <- [1..3], y <- [1..3], x + y == 4]
```

... it is equivalent to this use of `do` notation:

```
do x <- [1..3]
   y <- [1..3]
   guard (x + y == 4)
   return (x, y)
```

... which is equivalent to this use of `concatMap`:

```
concatMap (\x ->
    concatMap (\y ->
        if (x + y == 4) then [(x, y)] else []
        ) [1..3]
    ) [1..3]
```