# If-Then-Else inside List Monads do-notation

Tags: haskell, monads

I am trying to understand the concept of Monads and came across this list comprehension syntax for filtering sums from 2 lists.

```hs
largeSums = [i+j | i <- [10, 20, 30], j <- [1 , 2] , (i+j)>20]
```

I am trying to rewrite this using the do notation but do not understand what goes inside the `else` part:

```hs
largeSums = do
              i <- [10, 20, 30]
              j <- [1 , 2]
              if i+j > 20
               then return (i+j)
               else
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An empty list without `return` will work in that case. (which means 'no result for this combination of (i, j)'. On the other hand, `return (i+j)` equals `[i+j]`)

```hs
largeSums = do
              i <- [10, 20, 30]
              j <- [1 , 2]
              if i+j > 20
               then return (i+j)
               else []
```

However, it is more idiomatic to use [`guard :: (Alternative f) => Bool -> f ()`](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch13.html#x21-19900013.2.4).

```hs
import Control.Monad
largeSums = do
              i <- [10, 20, 30]
              j <- [1 , 2]
              guard (i+j > 20)
              return (i+j)
```

Related links:

- [How are list comprehensions implemented in Haskell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20687896/how-are-list-comprehensions-implemented-in-haskell)
- [Why is `guard` based on `Alternative`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44696944/why-is-guard-based-on-alternative)
- [The List monad - Learn You a Haskell for Great Good!](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads#the-list-monad)
- [List comprehension translations - Haskell Report 2010](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-430003.11)

Comment: `pure` > `return`